# Error in Login securables - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssms, errors, logins, role

I am using SQL Server 2017 and the latest SSMS version. When I click securables of login in SSMS, I see this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (SqlMgmt)
>
> ---
>
> Program Location:
>
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.PermissionsData.Securable.GetImage(SecurableType type)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.PermissionsSecurableSelector.InitializeBitmaps()
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.PermissionsSecurableSelector..ctor(IHelpProvider helpProvider, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Principal principal, PermissionsDetailsGrid permissionsGrid, Object connectionInfo, Boolean yukonOrGreater)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.PermissionsOfPrincipalsCore.InitializeSecurableSelector()
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.PermissionsOfPrincipalsCore..ctor(IHelpProvider helpProvider, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Principal principal, Object connectionInfo, Boolean yukonOrGreater, Boolean showColumnPermissionsInDetailsGrid)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.PermissionsServerPrincipal.InitializePermissionsCore()
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.PermissionsServerPrincipal.OnInitialization()
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.ViewSwitcherControlsManager.SetView(Int32 index, TreeNode node)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.ViewSwitcherControlsManager.OnBeforeSelection(Object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)

What can be the problem? I first thought it might be permission problem, but even if I use sysadmin login, I see this error every time.

Comment: Are you using the latest SSMS version (currently 19.1?

Comment: @DanGuzman Yes.

Comment: `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.PermissionsData.Securable.GetImage` Looks like your install is corrupt or something.

Comment: @SeanGallardy how did you know that?

Comment: I restarted SSMS a few times and it works for now. But I still want to know what was the problem.

Comment: How did I know what? You posted the stack trace. What other reasons would an application that works everywhere else, fail to find a picture which should be in a resource dll that it is shipped with?